# rxjs observable: Using some kind of await?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I've added an interceptor for my HTTP requests where I have to use the access token of my user instance. In my app component I initialise my user:

app.component.ts

```js
private async restoreUser(): Promise<UserModel | any> {
   // ... some view stuff

   return this.userService.restore()
      // login instance could be found
      .then(async () => {
         // ... some view stuff
      })

      // local storage is empty -> login is necessary
      .catch(async () => {
         // ... some view stuff

         this.subscription = this.networkSrv.getNetworkStatus()
            .subscribe((status: ConnectionStatus) => {
               if (status === ConnectionStatus.Online) {
                  // ... some view stuff
               } else {
                  // ... some view stuff
               }
            });
      });
}
```

http.interceptor.ts

```js
return this.userSrv.user.pipe(
   map((user: UserModel) => request.clone(
      {setParams: {'access-token': user.accessToken}}
   )),
   mergeMap(request => next.handle(request))
);
```

Now I would like to do a request by initialising my app. The problem is, that the user instance is empty and the application throws an error. Is there a way to do something like `await` -> so that the user instance is set?

Example:

```js
this.transmissionSrv.restoreQueue().then((projects: ProjectModel[]) => {
   this.transmissionSrv.transmitProjects(projects, true).subscribe(console.log);
});
```

Currently, I use the `setTimeout`-method, but that isn't the way I should do it, right? In addition, sorry for not being consistent by using Observer; Ionic often uses Promises(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adding a filter before your map. Using the filter, your map wont get call until the user is set.

```
return this.userSrv.user.pipe(
   filter(Boolean),
   map((user: UserModel) => request.clone(
      {setParams: {'access-token': user.accessToken}}
   )),
   mergeMap(request => next.handle(request))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could solve this.

1. Synchronously: Use an Angular `APP_INITIALIZER` (see [here](https://hackernoon.com/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-add41a6b7e)) to make the backend call and ensure the user object is present when the app bootstraps.
2. Asynchronously: Modify your existing application to store the user instance in an RxJs `BehaviorSubject` in a service somewhere and have components that depend on it subscribe to that `BehaviorSubject` wherever the user instance is needed. When the service constructs, have it make the backend call and stick the completed user instance inside the `BehaviorSubject` (`userSubject.next(user)`) when it's complete.